# measuring precision and recall

Tags: search, machine-learning, svm

We are building a text search solution and want a way to measure precision and recall of the system every time we add new document types. From reading some of the posts here it sounds like a machine learning  based solution is the way to go. Can a expert comment on this? We will then look to add machine learning folks to our team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the [F1-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) require knowledge about the correct class, rank of all samples obtains by evaluation querys, and you also need thoses evaluation querys.

- Any machine learning will need a large quantity of manual work to provided thoses samples and/or querys. So large that it wont save you any time.
- Another bad aspect of this evaluation is through to learning-related intrinsic errors. It will go with the growing size of the index of the search engine and the number of examples required. You never get a good evaluation.
- Forget machine-learning for the evaluation of search engine.
  Build by hand your tests querys and sample, by the time it will become big and reliable.
- If you really want machine-learning in your system, you should look at query pre-processing. Getting some meta-information about the query by another way (you say SVN, why not?) is generaly a good for performance and while it did'nt change the result, you can use the same sample for an end-to-end evaluation.
  That what I have done few years ago, but with naive baye classifier on natural langage analysis.

Comment: Thanks Mr. K. Interesting idea abt query pre-processing.